# Update Listbox after inserting a row into database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, sql-server-ce

I have bound a `ListBox` to a SQL CE database with this code:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:DatabaseWindow}}, Path=Database.Photos1}"
```

This `ListBox` is populated properly. But when I try to insert a row into the database (InsertOnSubmit + SubmitChagnes), the `ListBox` is not updated!

I have tried:

```
ListBox.Items.Refresh();

ListBox.GetBindingExpression(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateTarget();

ListBox.ItemsSource = null; 
ListBox.ItemsSource = this.Database.Table;
```

None of these helped. How can I update a `ListBox`?!

**PS:** After reloading the database, the row appears in the `ListBox`.
**PPS:** If anyone knows a tutorial for SQL CE with WPF where the insertion into a ListBox is shown - that would be great, too!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the data you're assigning to the ItemsSource implements INotifyCollectionChanged. (e.g. You can put your items into an ObservableCollection) 
Also, for changes to your indvidual items to be reflected you must be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's the reason why the ListBox is not updated *automatically*. But it would be enough if I could update it manually..